# Javascript: append to an array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, promise

I am trying to append numbers that I get from an api call (a promise) into an array. When I test the array's length it's always returning 1 as if each api call resets the array and puts in a new number.

here's the code:

The API call

```
 wiki()
  .page("COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria")
  .then((page) => page.fullInfo())
  .then((info) => {
    (data.confirmed.value = info.general.confirmedCases),
      (data.recovered.value = info.general.recoveryCases),
      (data.deaths.value = info.general.deaths);

   });

const data = {
  confirmed: { value: 0 },
  deaths: { value: 0 },
  recovered: { value: 0 },
};
```

Now I want to put the deaths count into an array, so that I have a list of numbers over the next days to keep track of.

```
  function countStats() {
  const counter = [];
  var deathCounter = data.deaths.value;
  counter.push(deathCounter);
  console.log(counter.length);
  return counter;
}

countStats();
```

every time the functions run (wiki() and countStats()) the counter array's length is always 1. Why is that?

Comment: I assume that because you create the counter every time new when countStats is called. you should put your const counter = [] into a higher scope

Comment: I already tried moving the counter up and out of the function and it didn't work. I suspect this has to do with the fact that the api call returns a promise?

Comment: Where exactly do you propose to store your data from day to day? You can't store it in Javascript. Javascript is not a storage medium.

Comment: *every time the functions run (wiki() and countStats()) the counter array's length is always 1* 1. That's exactly how it's supposed to work. In order to take advantage of the response returned, `countStats())` inside the last `.then()`. 

2. Exactly! Each call to `countStats())` initializes the array `counter` and adds **1** element to it. So the length of the array is 1, just as coded.

What exactly is your intention?

Comment: @PeterKA My intention is that if I run the wiki functions 10 times, I should have 10 elements in the array not 1.

Comment: Yes, we know that but you say "... so that I have a list of numbers over the next days". So where do you propose to store your data from day to day, given that it can't be stored in Javascript?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm going to put the numbers into an xml file. But that's not the issue here. I want to understand the logic of how to save the return from a Promise: why is it not working. I know that Javascript is not a storage medium.

Comment: @omar, it's very much the issue. See my answer.

Comment: ... unless @PeterKA 's assumptions are correct, in which case things get a bit simpler. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless ...

1. the data source provides multi-day data, or
2. you are going to run an extremely long javascript session (which is impractical and unsafe),

... then javascript can't, on its own, meet the objective of processing/displaying data arising from multiple days'.

Let's assume that the data source provides data that is correct for the current day.

You will need a permanent data store, in which scraped data can be accumulated, and retreived on demand. Exactly what you choose for your permanent data store is dependant on the environment in which you propose to run your javascript (essentially client-side browser or server-side NODE), and that choice is beyond the scope of this question.

Your master function might be something like this ...

```
function fetchCurrentDataAndRenderAll() {
    return fetchCurrentData()
    .then(writeToFile)
    .then(readAllFromFile)
    .then(data => {
        // Here, you have the multi-day data that you want.
        return renderData(data); // let's assume the data is to be rendered, say as a graph.
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // something went wrong
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
}
```

... and the supporting functions might be something like this:

```
function fetchCurrentData() {
    return wiki() // as given in the question ...
    .page("COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria")
    .then(page => page.fullInfo())
    .then(info => ({
        'timeStamp': Date.now(), // you will most likely need to timestamp the data 
        'confirmed': info.general.confirmedCases,
        'recovered': info.general.recoveryCases,
        'deaths': info.general.deaths
    }));
}

function writeToFile(scrapedData) {
    // you need to write this ...
    // return Promise.
}

function readAllFromFile() {
    // you need to write this ...
    // return Promise.
}

function renderData(data) {
    // you need to write this ...
    // optionally: return Promise (necessary if rendering is asynchronous).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()`. I take it that you'll not be requesting the same page 10 times but requesting a different page in each call e.g. `const Pages = ['COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6','page7','page8','page9','page10']`. Then you could make the 10 calls as follows:

```js
//const wiki = ......
const Pages = ['COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria','page2','page3','page4','page5','page6','page7','page8','page9','page10'];
let counter = [];

Promise.all(
    Pages.map(Page => wiki().page(Page))
)
    .then(results => {
        for (page of results) {
            let infoGeneral = page.fullInfo().general;
            counter.push(infoGeneral.deaths);
        }
        console.log( counter.length ); //10
        console.log( counter ); //[10 deaths results one for each page]
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: I will be requesting the same page actually (COVID-19_pandemic_in_Algeria). And then I will store for each day (adding a timestamp, see Roamer-1888's answer) the deaths count. Basically, in a 30 days period, I should have stored 30 deaths count